# Is there a tennis statistic about set-winners depending on who serves first?

Tags: tennis, statistics, serve

I have a feeling that serving first in a set is an advantage. Is there a statistic like "X % of the sets were won by the player who served first"?

Comment: Why do you feel that is an advantage (when you have to win by two)?

Comment: @Joe the first player has always the chance to rebreak

Comment: That implies that a player isn't trying to win every game though.

Comment: @joe no it's more about playing under pressure. I think that the pressure when you serve on 5-5 is bigger than when you serve on 5-6

Comment: I'd consider editing that into the question, then.  Your "I have a feeling" would be better fleshed out with a few sentences of the background for the question.

Comment: Tennis, as a sport, keeps very poor statistics about it's matches. This kind of stat, along with dozens of other useful stats, does not exist for any level of tour matches as far as I'm aware.

Comment: There are some older questions which seem to be (to some extent) related. For example: http://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/5657/in-tennis-is-there-any-advantage-to-decline-the-opening-serve http://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/5626/in-tennis-how-much-is-the-servers-advantage-diminished-if-the-game-goes-to-de http://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/5630/is-it-worth-fighting-to-hold-serve-in-a-losing-set

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As of now there are very few standardized statistics taken by the ATP or WTA concerning "percentage of sets won by player who served first". However, Professors Franc Klaassen and  Jan R. Magnus recently completed research on a number of Wimbledon tournaments and inspected several questions including the one concerning the outcomes of sets depending on who serves first.

You can find out more information here:http://www.janmagnus.nl/misc/wimbledon.pdf

However, you may have to pay to get the complete set of research. http://www.pinnaclesports.com/en/betting-articles/sport/live-tennis-betting-strategy summarizes that only "...48.2% of sets in the men’s singles are won by the player serving first. In the WTA? Just 50.1%".